# PySpark : how to juxtapose 2 columns?

Tags: pyspark

I have two DataFrames with one columns each (300 rows each) :

```
df_realite.take(1)
[Row(realite=1.0)]
df_proba_classe_1.take(1)
[Row(probabilite=0.6196931600570679)]
```

I would like to do one DataFrame with the two columns.
I tried :

```
    _ = spark.createDataFrame([df_realite.rdd, df_proba_classe_1.rdd]       , 
                               schema=StructType([ StructField('realite'     , FloatType() ) , 
                                                   StructField('probabilite' , FloatType() ) ]))
```

But

```
 _.take(10)
```

gives me empty values:

```
[Row(realite=None, probabilite=None), Row(realite=None, probabilite=None)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more concise way (or a way without a join), but you could always just give them both an id and join them like:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

df1 = df_realite.withColumn('id', functions.monotonically_increasing_id())
df2 = df_proba_classe_1.withColumn('id', functions.monotonically_increasing_id())

df1.join(df2, on='id').select('realite', 'probabilite'))
```

Comment: In general, this will not guarantee to join correctly.

Comment: @Pault : why doesn't it guarantee to join correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for and i would only recommend this method if your data is very small like it is in your case (300 rows) because collect() is not a good practice on tons of data otherwise go the join route with dummy cols and do a broadcast join so no shuffle occurs

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df1 = spark.range(10).select(col("id").cast("float"))
df2 = spark.range(10).select(col("id").cast("float"))

l1 = df1.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
l2 = df2.rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
list_df = zip(l1, l2)

schema=StructType([ StructField('realite', FloatType() ) , 
                    StructField('probabilite' , FloatType() ) ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(list_df, schema=schema)
df.show()

+-------+-----------+
|realite|probabilite|
+-------+-----------+
|    0.0|        0.0|
|    1.0|        1.0|
|    2.0|        2.0|
|    3.0|        3.0|
|    4.0|        4.0|
|    5.0|        5.0|
|    6.0|        6.0|
|    7.0|        7.0|
|    8.0|        8.0|
|    9.0|        9.0|
+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: I can't do that : I may have millions of lines further on

Comment: ok you said 300 rows each so i figured this was your final output

Comment: I wouldn't use spark for 300 rows :-p

Comment: obviously because it is intended for big data use cases however some people run it on their desktop for learning purposes i guess lol